# MariaDB and PHP - Queries are not working as should

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mariadb

What I am Running (so no one asks the obvious)

```
Database:                MariaDB ver. 10.0.20
Database client-version: libmysql - 5.6.27
PHP-version:             5.6.4
MYSQL-Extension:         mysqli
```

So I made the decision to immigrate my database to MariaDB. I have never had a problem with PHP and Mysql, but now I am learning that values are being selected weird from the database.

When I make the following query:

```
SELECT `stock_ticker`, `stock_simpleName` FROM `stocks` WHERE `stock_ticker` LIKE '%mon%' OR `stock_simpleName` LIKE '%mon%'
```

I get two results that are correct (`Monsanto` and `Mondelez`). When I run the same query in PHP, I get whatever the hell PHP wants to give me.

---

I have dissected the PHP code for days, and I promise, the code is sound. It has worked perfectly with other PHP and Mysql projects. I have determined it is a crossover between PHP and MariaDB possibly using the `mysqli` extension. I have no clue what the problem is though. Does anyone else know what it could be? Please help! This has been aggravating me for days. It might be a simple Google search, but everything I have searched has turned up nada.

Comment: What do you mean by "whatever the hell PHP wants to give you"? The results with PHP are different every time, even for the same query? Or that they are different from the MySQL results, but the same every time for the same queries?

Comment: What are the results that you get that aren't correct?

Comment: @Mike by that, it is the same everytime, but it gives me values that are not consistent with PHPMyAdmin MariaDB queries.

Comment: @JeffOrris They are consistent yet, incorrect results. Almost as if MariaDB ignores the sql if it is sent via PHP.

Comment: @Mitch Can you give some examples of an incorrect result?

Comment: `echo` the statement that is going wrong, together with the names it picked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your connection? Can you edit your question with more information about the database name etc? Perhaps, you might be connecting to the wrong database on PHP!

I had problems like this, but was my fault, I forgot to change the name on my PHP connections config..

Comment: I only have the one database. I does basic queries like `SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE stock_simpleName = '$value'`, But anymore complicated, the query gets wonky.

Comment: @mitch  read this https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/  might shed some insight